# How to pass square brackets [] as quotechar in pandas dataframe while reading from a csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My CSV file has commas at places where I don't want a column change. Those extra commas are placed in lists. I want to treat the list as a single cell output. Excel's CSV reader is reading just fine but I am not able to replicate this structure in a data frame.

Sample Raw Data:

```
1596173196213,20952342983,20952342987,"[[""change"",11067.5,133120],[""change"",11066.5,160660]]",[],
1596173196287,20952342987,20952342993,"[[""change"",11066.5,127460],[""change"",11066,78260]]",[],
1596173196319,20952342993,20952342999,"[[""delete"",1097,0],[""new"",1096,10]]",[],
1596173196322,20952342999,20952343000,"[[""change"",11006.5,60],[""change"",11007,104110]]",[],
1596173196323,20952343000,20952343001,[],"[[""change"",11134.5,44200],[""change"",11134,124200]]",
1596173196343,20952343001,20952343003,"[[""change"",11069.5,26150],[""change"",11070,2240]]",[],
1596173196410,20952343003,20952343011,[],"[[""change"",11083.5,104260],[""change"",11082.5,120850]]",
```

Correct Excel View:

[image]

I am trying different ways of passing square brackets but is it not working.
Eg:

```
df = pd.read_csv(result['Body'], quotechar='[]', index_col=0)
```

Comment: If not for the weird escape-quoting with the inner strings, it would have just worked... can you export that data differently? For example, it'd make more sense if `""simple""` was instead exported as `'simple'`.

Comment: What is generating this csv?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: it's a capture from WebSocket throwing events where each event is a row here. The headers are timestamp, previous change id, change id, and information in the change of state of an object. Changes are broadcasted in a list format.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: It's directly from the WebSocket of Deribit.com, a cryptocurrency exchange. We just saved the WebSocket JSON messages to CSV. Now, trying to read in a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Wait, what? So *you* are creating the CSV? I thought the CSV was coming from the websocket. If that is the case, I would fix the way you are saving this CSV. Or maybe, if you are just using `pandas`, consider `pickle`

Comment: So, I can read your csv just fine, using the default parameters... What *exactly* is the output you are getting?

Comment: @jaunpa.arrivillaga: I'll check on sample data. The whole CSV has 253k rows and I am getting this error: 

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 6 fields in line 34972, saw 11

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219120/discussion-between-danish-hasan-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).